# Migrating to Sping 6.X How to best migrate the Spring SecurityConfiguration for cors and matchers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am moving to Spring framework 6 and I have the following spring framework 2 code:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // Per https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166724/should-i-use-csrf-protection-on-rest-api-endpoints stateless
                // should be fine. CSRF is not required for API-only services
//                .csrf().disable() // this was in sprint 2.7
                .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
                .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
//                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("**/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                //.anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new AwsCognitoJwtAuthFilter(awsCognitoIdTokenProcessor), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
```

I figured out how to move '.csrf()' but I am having trouble moving .cors() and '.authorizeHttpRequests()'. Does anyone know how to migrate those (or have an example)? I am trying to use https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors but that is srping 5 not 6 and I have tried other research but most references are spring 5 or below ...

Comment: is there something hard to understand about the official migration docs in the official spring security documentation located on their webpage?

Comment: Hi, what I was not sure of was whether we had to chain calls such as:
```
request.requestMatchers("/pattern").permitAll();
request.requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
```
or whether we had to make the calls separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here on Stackoverflow are a lot of articles about this topic: **HOW TO**
but I always suggest to check documentation:
You should read these resources first of all:
[Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/index.html) , [Configuration Migrations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html)

In this case the `filterChain` will have next one body:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    http.cors(configuration -> configuration.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()));

    http.authorizeHttpRequests(request -> {
          request.requestMatchers("/pattern").permitAll();
          request.requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
          request.anyRequest().authenticated();
        })
    http.addFilterBefore(new AwsCognitoJwtAuthFilter(awsCognitoIdTokenProcessor), 
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Andrei Lisa pointed out:

```
request.requestMatchers("/pattern").permitAll();
request.requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
request.anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Is the correct way to do this.